# Reordering data and creating new data file

Tags: python

I am kind of new to programming and it is not my branch, but I need this task to analyze my data in a few days and now don't have enough time to be devoted to study of python. Let's say I have data file that looks like this:

```
0 2
0.5 8.4
1 354.8
0 41
0.5 2
1 48.8
```

Now I would need to create from this new data file that would look like this:

```
0 2 41
0.5 8.4 2
1 354.8 48.8
```

Whenever there is a zero value in first column it will start write data from the second column to the new column. The sequence of numbers in first column is always repeating. This up here is just a special case, there will be more repeating sequences with 0, 0.5 and 1.

I am kindly asking for some help with this task or for giving me some direction how to solve it in python.

Comment: So you want to group the values from the second and onward columns, according to the value in the first column? How much do you know how to do already in Python? For example, are you able to open the file and read lines of text? Are you able to interpret the values as numbers? (Does your task actually require treating them as numbers?)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel In the original file, there will be always two columns, first column is like x values in function y=f(x) and they are always the same. In second column are the y. So there will be like multiple curves y_i=f_i(x)  and I need to categorize them in the new data file in such way that in the first column are x values and in the others columns are the y_i. I have started to learn python a week ago just for a few hours, I worked with numpy and did some matrix operations, but not much with cycles or writing data to a file.  I read a little bit from Python Crash Course book.

Comment: @serafeim I am now trying to understand that code and how it could be generalize for unknown number of columns in the new data file. I maybe too simplyfied my original data. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: that is not difficult. `df2.shape` returns the number of rows and columns. then a loop would work just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pandas`. Assuming names on the columns:

```
df.columns = ['a', 'b']
df

    a     b
0  0.0    2.0
1  0.5    8.4
2  1.0  354.8
3  0.0   41.0
4  0.5    2.0
5  1.0   48.8
```

You can use:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['a'])['b'].apply(list).reset_index() # group by "a", get grouped "b" in list format
```

and get:

```
     a              b
0  0.0    [2.0, 41.0]
1  0.5     [8.4, 2.0]
2  1.0  [354.8, 48.8]
```

And finally extract the row data:

```
Row_list =[] 
for index, rows in df2.iterrows(): 
    my_list =[rows.a, rows.b]
    my_list= str(my_list).replace('[','').replace(']','')
    Row_list.append(my_list)
```

```
 print(Row_list)
 ['0.0, 2.0, 41.0', '0.5, 8.4, 2.0', '1.0, 354.8, 48.8']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use basic Python file and text methods for this (no need for third-party modules). A [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) is a convenient container datatype to store the data. For example:

```py
import collections

data = collections.defaultdict(list)

with open('input.txt', 'rt') as file:
    for line in file:
        n1, n2 = line.strip().split()
        data[n1].append(n2)

with open('output.txt', 'wt') as file:
    for key in sorted(data):
        file.write('%s %s\n' % (key, ' '.join(data[key])))
```